# Yocto QT5 duplicating layers in build config and custom layer's config

Tags: qt, yocto

I am trying to compile poky with QT5 for RaspberryPi3.
I found this guide: https://medium.com/@shigmas/yocto-pi-and-qt-e9f2df38a610
However, instead of `morty` I have decided to use `dunfell` branch.
I have adjusted the branch names accordingly, same with some renamed/deleted packages and paths.
I have managed to build the image almost flawlessly (QT libraries are installed; example binary - not, but it can be my fault/some compilation flags might have changed between versions; that's another topic).

However, I cannot quite put my finger on how the layers are exactly included:
if I used only bblayers.conf from my layer, bitbake would complain about not seeing `raspberrypi3` as a machine definition, not being able to include some files etc.
On the other hand, if I used only bblayers.conf in build directory, then bitbake would complain about not satisfied dependencies in `meta-mylayer`.
I ended up with duplicating most layer entires, i.e.:

```
#build/conf/bblayers.conf
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-raspberrypi \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-qt5 \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/meta-mylayer \
  "
```

while meta-mylayer's config looks stunnigly similar

```
#meta-mylayer/conf/bblayers.conf
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-raspberrypi \
  /home/<username>/yoctoproject/poky/meta-qt5 \

  "
```

Again, as I have previously stated: the whole setup seems to be working reasonably in the end, but nevertheless the layer config I have feels a bit "off", or counter-intuitive to say the least. Which part of the docs have I potentially missed (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any `bblayers.conf` in your layer but there must be a `layer.conf` file in your meta layer.

You should read the official documentation [Understanding and creating layers](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#understanding-and-creating-layers)